How to unmarshal JSON with some known and some unknown fields in a nested structure
I have following JSON:
{
    "common": {
        "a": "xyz",
        "b": "qwe"
    },
    "events": [
        {
            "c": "lll",
            "?": "eee",
            "??": "ppp"

        }
    ]
}

I know that it has the "a", "b" and "c" fields but I don't know the names of other fields. I want to unmarshal it in the following structure:
type Request struct {
    Common CommonParams `json:"common"`
    Events []Event      `json:"events"`
}

type CommonParams struct {
    A string `json:"a"`
    B string `json:"b"`
}

type Event struct {
    C string                 `json:"c"`
    X map[string]interface{} `json:?????`
}

How do I do that?
The solutions here don't work as the fields in this JSON are in a nested structure.

You cannot do this. You cannot have some fields unmarshaled into dedicated struct fields and the "rest" into a map. You must use a map for Event (or a json.RawMessage and some more logic).

maybe you can use this?
var res map[string]any
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &res)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

and use loop for extract unknow fields like this
if events, ok := res["events"].([]any); ok {
    for _, event := range events {
        if eventMap, ok := event.(map[string]any); ok {
            for key, value := range eventMap {
                fmt.Printf("Field: %s, Value: %v\n", key, value)
            }
        }
    }
}


for my full code test, you can see on https://go.dev/play/p/5-uool0nw4t
